# iOS phonegap/cordova file browser plugin

Tags: ios5, phonegap-plugins

I've been working on phonegap/cordova project. My task is to download a file from a webserver , save it to iPad,iPhone native file system. I  my view section I need to view these files stored on my native file system. I've managed the download part just cant figure out how to do the file browser part.I am not Objective C programmer hence, i wont be coding, but I can tweak  code. If anybody knows any code snippet or **cordova/phonegap plugin**  which can help please let me know.

Thanks!